# Is there some iterative way to compute heading and GPS projection at the same time?

Tags: c, gps, coordinate-systems, heading

I have the following situation:

An off-road machine has a GPS antenna that is not at the center of the rear axle (this point is my path-tracking-control point). Let's say it's 3 meters from the rear axle and 2 meters from the left.

So, I should translate the GPS point to the center of the rear axle. For that, I need the current machine heading, given by delta latitude and delta longitude. So far, so good.

However, as my machine is turning, the heading of the rear axle and the heading of the GPS antenna are not the same.

For those, I'm looking for a method to, given an initial heading (GPS heading), start computing the antenna projection, and from that projection, calculate another heading (rear axle heading) until the system converges.

**EDIT 1** - Some drawings
POI goes for Point of Interest

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like some algebra and geometry question (vaguely stated btw) rather than programming.

Comment: Is the rear axle not fixed? If not, what governs how it turns? If it is not fixed, how is it connected to the vehicle, and how is its motion constrained? If it is mounted so it can pivot, is that mount in the center of the axle? In that case, the center of the rear axle is always in the same place relative to the vehicle, so the turning of the axle is irrelevant for calculating its position relative to any other part of the vehicle. Its heading might be different, but why would you need the axle’s heading? Is it driving the vehicle? You should add details.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Finding a solution by computing iterations to convergence is a programming question.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the responses.

Just added some pics as an edit